# Cannot share internet connection from Windows 10 laptop to phone

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I’m using a LAN cable for this. I don’t know why, but since I upgraded to Windows 10, I can’t share my connection (from my laptop to my phone) any more, even when I use Connectify or Windows 10 wifi hotspot. However, when my friend used my LAN cable, she could share the connection just fine! This is definitely my laptop’s fault.

Comment: Do you want to share Windows 10 laptop connection (i.e. reverse tethering) through only wifi or with USB? Mention phone type i.e Android or Windows?

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, “I can't share my connection (from laptop to my phone) anymore.” It proves that your wireless adapter supports hosted networks.

You could try to upgrade the wireless network card driver from the official website of the manufacturer. If it doesn’t work, go to device manager > wifi adapter > update drivers > browse my computer for driver software  ? let me check for a list of device drivers on my computer.. then pick the one that pre-dates your windows 10 intallation.

Also reset TCP/IP to check. Using the command “netsh int ip reset”.